# .htaccess for don't redirect if has some string

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

i have a .htaccess file with below rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.ir [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.ir/$1 [L,R=301]
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^item/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([^/]+)$ item.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
...
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

my url is

```
http://domain.ir/item/{number}/{title}
```

and work perfect, but i have a payment on my site that after success transaction return below URL

```
http://domain.ir/item/?Authority=000000000000000000000000000071165119&Status=OK
```

now my problem is that when return this URL, page redirect to my homepage and i can't process returned URL
i want if my page has Authority in URL .htaccess don't redirect to another homepage

Comment: If you directly enter `http://domain.ir/item/?Authority=000000000000000000000000000071165119&Status=OK` does it redirect to home page? Can you comment `ErrorDocument` line and retest?

Comment: Maybe return URL just exit by `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`. L means last, and LiteSpeed Web Server will honor the rule.  Try remove `L` see if it helps.